# How to loop innerHTML property binding using angular and typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to display the innerHtml property binding details using ngFor.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let n of NotificationData">
    {{n.NotificationID}} <label [innerHtml]="n.NotificationText | StyleHtml"></label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried the above code. but I am not able to get the NotificationText values.

[![NotificationData values][1]][1]

Comment: Can you show the data value for `NotificationData`?

Comment: Is it possible for you to add the NotificationData data. To see the data you are looping? is `NotificationID` showing? have you try only displaying `{{n.NotificationText}}` wwithout the innedHtml? does it work?

Comment: is there an error denoting sanitize HTML?

Comment: From your posted screenshoot, there is no `NotificationText` property.

Comment: @YongShun I have attached my NotificationData

Comment: @FlorenciaCames NotificationID is showing. and I tried that {{n.NotificationText}} but this is not working

Comment: Your data doesn't have `NotificationText` property, are you referring `NotificationName` or `NotificationDescription`?

Comment: @user123 I was going to say the same as the comment next to mine from Yong Shung

Comment: NotificationName and NotificationDescription both

Comment: In that case you shoul replace the value from `NotificationText` to  `NotificationName ` or `NotificationDescription` or you can join them by doing this `<div [innerHtml]="n.NotificationName + n.NotificationDescription | StyleHtml"></div>`

Comment: yes I am getting the data. it's my mistake. Thank u guys

Answer (score 0):

I use `innerHTML` to show. You try this way

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let n of NotificationData">
   <label [innerHTML]="n.NotificationText"></label>
  </li>
</ul>
```